# What is the difference between "Shared Folders" in vmWare vs a mapped network drive?

Tags: vmware-fusion

How do "Shared folders" work in vmWare Fusion? Are they just mapped network drives under the covers or are they using a different technology?

Comment: Virtualization system shared folders do not use the network as an intermedairy, are not accessible by any entity other than the specific  guest and the host, and are implemented in the virtualization platforms software. Completely different kind of animal.

Comment: I think the "Shared Folders" in this case are shared folders using UNC path instead of mapped letter path...